# Failed to run allure generate command . ERROR :ClassNotFoundException io.qameta.allure-result.CommandLine

Tags: java, python-3.x, pytest, aws-codebuild, allure

I am facing the below error while running the allure generate command for my pytest testsuite.

## Error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class io.qameta.allure-result.CommandLine
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.qameta.allure-result.CommandLine

## setup:

> Machine: Amazon linux 2 machine

> Running command echo $JAVA_HOME
> /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64

`echo $PATH has '/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-amazon-corretto.x86_64/bin'`

Please let me know how to correct it. It will be a greate help. Blocked because of this since many days.

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine now. Closing this question.
(Installing allure-pytest-bdd-temp using pip instead of using requirements.txt solved this problem)